# Does WordPress default CSS have Grids?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

WordPress 'out of the box' comes with some javascript to allow you to send AJAX requests, show the image select dialog, etc.

Does WordPress 'out of the box' come with any default CSS? Especially for use in themes? As an example, does it have its own Grid CSS setup where I can create grids without needing an external dependency like Bootstrap Twitter?

**Usecase:**
I am developing a simple plugin similar to `Visual Composer`. It will allow the user to create HTML components. If WordPress has default CSS for grids, I can create the HTML components using that grid CSS rather than relying on Bootstrap Twitter (which could conflict with the users theme).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't come with ajax code but there is a hook called `wp_ajax_` that you can add custom functions to and a `admin-ajax.php` file that is used to process ajax requests. See [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/) for a guide on how to implement ajax code in wordpress.

Wordpresses default templates don't come with grid CSS.